# Как регулировать ширину строки таблицы?

Tags: html, jquery, css, json

Как, регулировать ширину отдельной ячейки в таблице ? Пытаюсь увеличить либо умен шить ширину одной ячейки а сдвигаются все ячейки , подскажите , что не так делаю ? И как правильно ?

Когда обедееняю все ячейки в одну то ширина вообще не регулируется...

```css
@charset "utf-8";
 html,
body {
  width: 1920px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.top_baner {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url(../img/baner_top.png);
  padding: 155px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.top_baner > .content_wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1214px;
}
.top_baner > .content_wrapper > .top_line {
  width: inherit;
  background-image: url(../img/Top_logo.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0% 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  height: 81px;
}
.top_baner > .content_wrapper > .top_line > p {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 63px 0 0 42px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.top_baner > .content_wrapper > h1 {
  margin: 207px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.top_baner > .content_wrapper > h2 {
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.top_baner > .content_wrapper > hr {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  border: none;
  height: 1px;
  background: white;
  margin: 40px 0px auto;
}
.top_baner > .content_wrapper > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  width: 157px;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 5.5;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
}
.second_block {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
/*Second_block*/

.second_block > .content_wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1214px;
}
.second_block > .left_block {
  float: left;
  width: 441px;
  margin: 284px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0 353px 0;
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
.second_block > .left_block > h1 {
  font-size: 53px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.second_block > .left_block > hr {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  border: none;
  height: 1px;
  background: #000000;
  margin: 16px 0 auto;
}
.second_block > .left_block > h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 55px 0 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.second_block > .right_block {
  /* position: relative; */
  /* clear: both; */
  float: right;
  width: 1126px;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(316deg);
  top: -597px;
  right: 26px;
}
/*.right_block > ul:first-child {
 height: 545px;
 width: 1145px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding: 56px 0;
}


.right_block > ul:last-child.{
    height: 150px;
    width: 1140px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0px 0;
}
*/

.second_block > .right_block > .firsrt_bloks > li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.second_block > .right_block > .sekond_block > li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.second_block > .right_block > ul > li > a {
  width: 193px;
  height: 193px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0px 0 10px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.firsrt_bloks {
  */;
  /* padding-top: 112px; */
  /* padding-bottom: 525px; */
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  height: 206px;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.second_block {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 890px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
.second_block > .left_block > h1 {
  font-size: 53px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.second_block > .left_block > hr {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  border: none;
  height: 1px;
  background: #000000;
  margin: 16px 0 auto;
}
.second_block > .left_block > h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 55px 0 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.second_block > .right_block {
  float: right;
  width: 1126px;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(316deg);
  top: -597px;
  right: 26px;
}
ul.firsrt_bloks {
  padding-bottom: 525px;
  padding-top: 112px;
}
.firsrt_bloks {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  height: 206px;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.second_block > .right_block > .firsrt_bloks > li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.second_block > .right_block > ul > li > a {
  width: 193px;
  height: 193px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0px 0 10px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.second_block > .right_block > ul > li > a > img {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(406deg);
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom\: 1;
  padding: 1;
}
a#id1 {} a#id2 {} a#id3 {} a#id4 {
  clear: left;
  margin-left: 213px;
}
a#id5 {} a#id6 {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
a#id7 {
  clear: left;
  margin-left: 621px;
}
a#id8 {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.second_block > .right_block > ul > li > a > p {
  margin: 42px 0 0 0;
  padding: 33px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(404deg);
  width: 140px;
  clear: both;
}
.width_zone > img {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin: -59px 0 0 0;
}
.second_block > .right_block > ul > li > a > p > img {
  margin: -22px 56px auto;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  float: left;
}
.second_block > .right_block > ul > li > a:hover {
  background: #28282e;
  color: white;
}
/*sirt_blocked*/

.third {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1200px;
  background: #28282e;
}
.width_zone {
  margin-bottom: 75px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 320px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
a.next_slayd_1,
a.next_slayd_2,
a.next_slayd_3 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 74px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
.slayder {
  float: right;
  width: 600px;
  height: 445px;
}
.togles {
  background-image: url(../img/icons.png);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  width: 222px;
  height: 47px;
  margin-left: 186px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.third > .content_wrapper {
  width: 1214px;
  height: 890px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
.third > .content_wrapper > p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 240px;
}
.third > .content_wrapper > .left_block {
  float: left;
  width: 441px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
.third > .content_wrapper > .left_block > h1 {
  font-size: 53px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  color: #FFF;
}
.third > .content_wrapper > .left_block > hr {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  border: none;
  height: 1px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 16px 0 auto;
}
.third > .content_wrapper > .left_block > h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 55px 0 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  color: #FFF;
}
.third > .content_wrapper > .left_block > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  width: 157px;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 5.5;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin: 40px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}
/*white_blog    */

.white_blog {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1200px;
  background: #FFF;
}
.content_wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1214px;
}
.white_blog > .content_wrapper > p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
.first_line > h1 {
  float: left;
  font-size: 53px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333333;
}
.first_line > hr {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  border: none;
  height: 1px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 16px 0 auto;
}
.first_line > p {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 24px 0 0 622px;
  width: 406px;
}
.white_blog > .content_wrapper:last-child > p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 115px;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
/*Table*/

table {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  color: #000;
  border-spacing: 1px;
  /* Расстояние между ячейками */
}
tr:nth-child(2) > td {
  background: #fff;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
tr:nth-child(1) {} tr:nth-child(2) {} tr:nth-child(3) {} tr:nth-child(4) {} tr:nth-child(5) {}
/*forth_block*/

.forth_block {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1041px;
  background: #8C8C8C;
}
.forth_block > .content_wrapper {
  width: 1214px;
  height: 890px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
.controlers {
  margin-left: 263px;
  float: left;
}
.inputs {} tr:nth-child(3) > td {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 425px;
  padding-top: 58px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_wrapper">
  <p></p>
  <div class="first_line">
    <h1>Read our minds</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquet purus et orci tincidunt tempus. Duis ultricies, nibh.</p>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Title &amp; Description</td>
        <td>date</td>
        <td>who</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Weekly Digital Roundup</td>
        <td>08/05/2014</td>
        <td>Adam Campbell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="4" colspan="2">Wi-Fi apple care volume reminder controls. My stations folders mac power ultimate upgrade. Shop online quicktime trackpad server aperture rumors education safari one to one.</td>

      </tr>


    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если сдвигаются те ячейки, которые находятся в той же колонке, то это обычное поведение для таблиц, и когда вы изменяете ширину одной ячейки, то ширина будет изменяться также у всех ячеек, находящихся в том же столбце.

Answer (score -1):

Может, это из-за того, что столбца 3, а в строке (точнее в строках) про "Wi-fi apple..." `colspan="2"`?